# Alternatives for the TreeSet.headSet(someElement).size() with reduced time complexity

Tags: java, treeset, sortedset

I need to find the number of elements smaller than a particular Element *e* on a TreeSet.
But the headSet.size() of the TreeSet has time complexity linear to the size of the subset as it iterates all the elements in the subset to get the count. Is there any other way i can get faster than this running time ? At-least a logarithmic time complexity would be better. I know a binary indexed tree would be useful for this problem. But i would like to know if this can be done in native implementation of a Balanced Tree like TreeSet ?